# efficient way to manipulating numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

So let's say I have a numpy array `a= np.array([1,2,3,4,5])` and a value `x=4`, then I want to create a numpy array of values `-1` and `1` where there is a `1` in the `4th` position and `-1` everywhere else.

Here is what I tried:

```
for i in range(a):
    if i == x:
        a[i]=1
    else:
        a[i]=-1
```

Is this good?

Comment: Yes its good, whats your concrete question?

Comment: Ok cool, is there a way to do it in one line of code?

Comment: Yes, remove breaklines

Comment: `range(a)` doesn't work in your example. It would need to be `range(len(a))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not numpy'ish

```
b=-np.ones(a.shape)
b[x] = 1
```

Edit: added example

```
import numpy as np

x=3
a= np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b=-np.ones(a.shape)
b[x] = 1
print(b)

> [-1. -1. -1.  1. -1.]
```

Comment: Or `b=-np.ones(a.shape, dtype=int)` if ints are required, as otherwise they're floats

Comment: Construction of b could be slightly optimized with np.full_like(a, -1). Less operations,  less mem consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

a= np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) 

x=np.where(a==4, 1, -1)

print(x)
```

Output:

```py
[-1 -1 -1  1 -1]

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
b = np.array([1 if i == 4 else -1 for i in range(a.shape)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative. Utilizes casting from bool to int.

b=2*(a==x)-1